# How to get the dropdown list index

Tags: c#

I need to find the drop-down list index value based on the drop down list selected value. but every time if I select the value from the drop-down list its shows the index as 0. could anyone help with this. thanks in advance

Comment: When you get selected value? post code behind

Comment: can you please tell us which application you are using Combobox (ASP.Net or windows forms)?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Selected index = " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

You can put the above in a SelectedIndexChanged event just like below:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Selected index = " + comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

EDIT: If you're using ASP.NET just use the OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs) of the DropDownList class and the SelectedValue property. Thanks Tim for pointing this out.

Comment: I assume its ASP.NET due to the `SelectedValue` hint